# Huge val_loss in tensorflow loaded model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence

I've trained my model and here's it's out:

```
Epoch 1/40
266/266 [==============================] - 121s 339ms/step - loss: 1.7454 - accuracy: 0.6316 - val_loss: 0.9347 - val_accuracy: 0.7357
Epoch 2/40
266/266 [==============================] - 77s 290ms/step - loss: 0.9941 - accuracy: 0.6985 - val_loss: 1.2392 - val_accuracy: 0.7384
...........
Epoch 39/40
266/266 [==============================] - 77s 290ms/step - loss: 0.1972 - accuracy: 0.9327 - val_loss: 0.7653 - val_accuracy: 0.8859
Epoch 40/40
266/266 [==============================] - 77s 290ms/step - loss: 0.1981 - accuracy: 0.9364 - val_loss: 1.9873 - val_accuracy: 0.9029
```

I've saved it by using `model.save()` and then later opened it by using `keras.models.load_model()` and started to train and test on data which was formated **exactly as previous** for training and it showed me this:

```
Epoch 1/40
387/387 [==============================] - 142s 306ms/step - loss: 0.5836 - accuracy: 0.8123 - val_loss: 1242122753187902574821376.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.5508
Epoch 2/40
387/387 [==============================] - 115s 297ms/step - loss: 0.4273 - accuracy: 0.8527 - val_loss: 541728415516389919424512.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.5508
Epoch 3/40
387/387 [==============================] - 112s 290ms/step - loss: 0.3686 - accuracy: 0.8726 - val_loss: 1872626124559019711397888.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.5508
```

Why this val_loss is so huge and how can I fix it?

I've tried to do do exactly the same model and then load there only weights by using `model.load_weights()` and nothing changed

P.S. here's full code https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1USnoRiH8LbqymqpqtLpfJNJ7f66UilLL?usp=sharing

Comment: you haven't posted any code, any data...  My guess is that your new training data is different than the previous one, but without seeing code or data is impossible to know

Comment: Sorry, here it is